# Servidor no reconoce archivos php

Tags: php, windows, batch

Tengo este php simple,es solo una conexion,de forma local(mi computadora)
al ejecutarlo desde un batch si funciona,pero al hacerlo desde el server me marca el sig error
cabe decir si lo pongo en la carpeta httdoc y lo ejecuto via web si funciona(pero no me interesa ya que quiero que este se ejecute a una hora determinada desde el batch)
alguna idea por que no me reconoce las librerias? 
gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás haya dos instalaciones de php? (con diferente php.ini) Una en program files y otra en otro sitio, que es la que se utilizaría via web.

Comment: Prueba usando phpinfo() para que veas que archivo de configuración php.ini (si es que alguno) se esta leyendo cuando lo corres como Batch.  `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`